# Set Handles to conform a bezier curve with N points to a different curve

Tags: geometry-nodes

How can I conform my new curve (green) to a reference curve (red) (if it's even possible)?

[image]

I thought I can capture the original curve tangents and then use them to align the handles but... I can't understand how to offset the new handles based on those tangents.

[image]

the scene on [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ambquzc5s9x4j72bvsqsl/conform_curve.blend?rlkey=qd5592pttsuvi4ryc3eutzt2v&dl=1)